# import SVG in es module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, import

I am trying to import an SVG in my node module:

```
import * as example from "./assets/asset1.svg"
```

But it throws me an error:

> Unknown file extension ".svg" for C:\path-to-my-project\assets\asset1.svg

> code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'

How can I fix this issue?

I could import other assets, like jsons using the following approach:

```
import * as asset_json from "./assets/asset1.json" assert { type: "json" };
```

Thanks

Comment: SVG is not a javascript code. You should link to it or read the file using io.